# Effect of the Java bytecode instruction combination on the operand stack

Tags: java, assembly, bytecode

For the sequences of Java bytecode instructions written manually using ASM, is there a way to access the status of the stack? For instance, for a combination like below:

```
ILOAD_0,ILOAD_1,IADD,DUP -> 1,1
```

The motive here is to write test code to verify that the a given set of instructions leads to a given stack such as

```
assert getCurrentStackLength() == 2
```

or

```
assert getTopElement() == (int) 1
```

and so on.

Comment: You are specifically asking about Java bytecodes, correct?

Comment: Yes. JVM instructions or Java bytecode.

Comment: So you pretty much want to execute it? Your best bet is probably to generate them in a method in a generated class, append code to output the state of the stack and run that. Then get the result and assert whatever you want to assert.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, how do I "output the state of the stack"?

Comment: @shail619: that's the tricky part ;-) I have never tried that and I assume that verification and type checking might make that difficult (or impossible?). But other than this approach I can't think of a pure Java solution to this problem (unless you want to re-implement the JVM, which brings its own set of problems).

Comment: Does it mean that the stack itself is completely internal to the VM and strictly inaccessible (this would imply one has to manually infer the status of the stack by going through the instruction semantics)?

Comment: @shail619: I know of no other official way to access the stack than via bytecode in the current method. The debugging APIs (mostly [JVM TI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html)) *might* help with that as well.

Answer (score 2):

The stack is an internal detail of the JVM and may not actually exist in practice.

Typical JVMs have two modes of operation - interpretation and JIT compilation. Interpertation actually simulates the stack and locals. JIT compilation compiles everything to machine code, so there's no such thing as an operand stack or local variable table.

Basically, what you'd have to do is look through the code of your JVM, find a way to force it to always interpret your code, add debugging code to print out the stack, etc. and then recompile and rebuild everything. Obviously not a task for the fainthearted.

The bigger question however is why you would want to do this. Are you trying to unit test the JVM? Any code you write is more likely to have bugs than what you're testing.

If all you want to do is find out the stack and locals state at a particular point in the bytecode, all you need is a static verifier. There are plenty out there. I've written [one that's on Github](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) if you're interested.

Comment: Yes, I would like to take a look at it.

Comment: Here's the one I wrote. It's written in Python, so it may be difficult to use from Java though. It's mostly designed for static analysis. Anyway, if you have any questions, feel free to ask. https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau

Comment: Thanks @Antimony. Going through the JVM documentation in more detail, I have come across the attribute [StackMapTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.4) which seems to provide precisely the information I was initially looking for.

Comment: @shail, that only tells you the state at the beginning of each basic block, and only in 51.0 and most 50.0 classes. It's intended as an aid to the JVM to speed up classfile verification.

Comment: I agree. However, if the bytecode combination to be tested is limited to this "basic block", would that not still be useful?